# How to get all "a" tags containing a certain "href" format using Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, xpath

I am trying to get all links from a website using XPATH, the URL format is pretty specific but dynamic.

The URL I'd like to get has the format of "/static_word/random-string-with-dashes/random_number" (3 segments: 1st static, 2nd random string, 3rd random number). Can you guys help me to accomplish this?

I was trying to do it with regex but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
import ssl
import requests
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
myRequest = requests.get("https://somesecureurl.com/", headers=headers)
webpage = html.fromstring(myRequest.content)
theLinks = webpage.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'^/static_word/[A-Za-z0-9_-]/[0-9]$')]")

print(theLinks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [matches()](http://zvon.org/comp/r/ref-XPath_2.html#Functions~matches) which you can use to match required string by regex:

```
//a[matches(@href,'^/static_word/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/[0-9]+$')]
```

but AFAIK `lxml` doesn't support XPath 2.0 functions

You can try this one instead:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '/static_word/') and 
    (string-length(@href)-string-length(translate(@href, '/', '')))=3 and
    number(substring-after(substring-after(@href, '/static_word/'), '/'))>=0]
```

Above predicate should match:

- `starts-with(@href, "/static_word/")` - `a` node with `@href` that starts with  substring `'/static_word/'`
- `(string-length(@href)-string-length(translate(@href, '/', '')))=3` - also `@href` contains exactly 3 slashes
- `number(substring-after(substring-after(@href, '/static_word/'), '/'))>=0` - the last sub-string is any positive number

This looks awful, but should work :)

Comment: Hello @Andresson, thank you for the very useful explanation. I've tried your example but I get an empty value, and this is wrong :(  there are more than a thousand links using this format.

Comment: Yes. First one failed, this didn't fail but did not match any

Comment: Can you share one of the links you want to match? The provided XPath successfully matches something like `<a href="/static_word/some_other_string/1234">Link</a>`....